# Open Source projects with dependencies

Tags: c#, open-source, dependencies

I have a question regarding c# open-source projects and dependencies. For example, I am currently working on a few projects. One is a C# project that produces a class library with specific functionality. This project should be hosted as other projects will find this functionality useful.

The next project I'm working on requires a reference to the class library project which is under separate version control.

So how can I structure an open-source c# project with a dependency to the class library project without including the source code of the class library project?

Any example projects to study would be great too! :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If the open source depency is on listed on [Nuget](http://nuget.org/) then the easiest way is to add the Nuget package, and make sure your packages folder and packages config file is included in the project.

Unless you want the actual source, then this is the easiest way to add binary dependencies. It includes the PDBs so you get the lines of the original source code.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is very helpful as I didn't know about NuGet. However, ideally I would like to follow the traditional path of source distribution rather than binaries if possible. I will however take a close look at NuGet. I need to support Mono too though, so if NuGet is only for Visual Studio I don't think I'll be able to use it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Include a cmake script to gather dependencies in the application source code. The cmake script will check for dependencies, and any that are missing will be downloaded.

You could experiment with the cmake script being a pre-build step in the solution; But for now dependencies are updated manually.

The script is the same no matter which system it is on, which is the beauty of cmake's script mode.

Although this is a bit clunky, it seems about the best way to include a source-code version of an external dependency which is not a part of the applications version control.

as an example, you can get a launchpad project:

```
bzr branch lp:~brian-sidebotham/+junk/valverschatcam
```

from the root of this project, simply run:

```
cmake -P build.cmake
```

Obviously the script should probably be called deps.cmake or similar instead of build right now.